# Dynamically added dropdown navigate with arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a custom dropdown where I add values dynamically. Now I want to navigate with "up" and "down" arrow through dropdown values and select value with enter, how can it be done?

It can be jquery or js.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var states = {
        'Color': ['red', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', 'Dark Green', 'Light Grey','red', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', 'Dark Green', 'Light Grey','red', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', 'Dark Green', 'Light Grey','red', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', 'Dark Green', 'Light Grey','red', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', 'Dark Green', 'Light Grey','red', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', 'Dark Green', 'Light Grey'],
        'Numbers': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four','one', 'two', 'three','one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'four']
    };

    $('input').on('keyup', function () {
        match($(this).val());
    });

    function match(str) {
        str = str.toLowerCase();
        $('.dialog').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < states.Color.length; i++) {
            if (states.Color[i].toLowerCase().includes(str)) {
                var mStart = states.Color[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(str);
                var mEnd = mStart + str.length;
                var text = states.Color[i].slice(0, mStart);
                text += '<span class="match">';
                text += states.Color[i].slice(mStart, mEnd);
                text += '</span>';
                text += states.Color[i].slice(mEnd);
                $('.dialog').append('<div>' + text + '</div>');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.dialog > div > .match {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.dialog {background-color:lightcoral; max-height: 90px;  width:112px;    overflow: scroll;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<div class="dialog">
```

Comment: Where are the up and down arrows located on the UI?  Or are you referring to the up and down keys on the keyboard?

Comment: @delvin carnate, yes, up and down on keyboard - 38,40,13

Comment: Your code is working https://jsfiddle.net/smahajan89/1s73mvpw/1/ 
What else you want to achieve ?

Comment: @Sarvesh Mahajan I want it to go through the drop-down list with key arrows  like "down" and "up" and select on "enter" key

Comment: So, basically, you want to replace the functionality of the normal `select` element with your own custom? This is do-able, but it does break the traditional UX of, when the user is in a text input, having the up or down arrow move to the beginning or end of the inputted text. Rewrote it without jQuery, here's everything but enter key working: https://repl.it/@TobiasParent/DropdownQuestionSO